# How can i add number to a javascipt Span ID

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML webpage that gets a number from an external javascript using this:

```
<span id="numl"></span>
```

but I want to add the number 10 to the generated number, how can I do this, for example, the code above gets number "8" but instead of showing "8" it should add 10 to it which would be equals to "18"

I'm new to javascript and don't know how to do this

Comment: You need to show us the javascript code for fetching the number, and adding it to `#numl`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should increment the number by ten.

To resolve the timing issue you can use a Mutation Observer to change the number as soon as it is changed.

```js
//source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe
// identify an element to observe
const elementToObserve = document.getElementById("num1");

//global variable to monitor changecount
window.changeCount = 0;

// create a new instance of `MutationObserver` named `observer`,
// passing it a callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
    if(window.changeCount == 0) //so it wont recursively increment by 10
    {
      element = document.getElementById("num1");//get Element
      element.innerText = parseInt(element.innerText) + 10; //increment innerText by 10
    }
    window.changeCount = window.changeCount + 1; //increment change count by one

});

// call `observe()` on that MutationObserver instance,
// passing it the element to observe, and the options object
observer.observe(elementToObserve, {subtree: true, childList: true});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the javascript file is in an external file which I don't have access to, how do I add this code in my HTML file please.

Comment: You can create a new javascript file and add it to your HTML Document like explained here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: Thanks, im new to javascript, added internal javascript to my HTML, what should I add to my HTML code to show the number?

Comment: The code from my answer. Depending on when the number is loaded into your HTML Element it will either work or not. Copy pasting the above code will only work if the Number is loaded into your element from the "beginning" (aka. when DOM has loaded). If it is loaded by some external script it will work if you start the above code after the external script has loaded the number.

Comment: ok, looks like the external javascript loads the number a little bit late, like after 7 seconds

Comment: I don't recommend waiting for 7 seconds but if you want to you can do that with Javascript of course... I will update my response for detailed help

Comment: Updated the response for you